# Google+ related page appearing in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-plus, social-networking

Gmail have been displaying related Google+ pages on the right of the page when I open certain emails. It looks like this:

[image: Google plus related page display]

I can't find any documentation on it though and trying to figure out how to associate a particular email address with a Google+ page. For example, say we have a Google+ page http://plus.google.com/example and we have linked it to its official domain http://example.com - it does not automatically display the Google+ page in Gmail next to all emails that come from the example.com domain.

I am trying to specifically have the related page display from all emails that come from foo@example.com - but I can't seem to find work out what I need to do to link that email to the Google+ page.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This can help you :) [Enabling Google+ related pages widget in Gmail](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3190197?hl=en)

Comment: is this still valid? I think the link doesn't work correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what Google says:

> In order to begin using this feature, you must create a Google+ page
>   that meets several criteria:
>
> - Your Google+ page must be website linked with the domain from which    you’ll be sending emails.
> - In general, the sender’s domain for the    email must match that of the verified website. If your website is    verified as
>     http://www.example.com, the email must be sent from the
>     @example.com domain. If you send email from a subdomain of your
>     verified domain (such as @xyz.example.com), we’ll match it to your
>     page unless there’s a different Google+ page associated with that
>     address.
> - Your email must be digitally signed with DKIM or SPF.
> - You must send at least 1,000 emails a week from the domain.

Comment: is this still valid? the source link doesn't exist anymore :(

Comment: @webpaul: it was working 2 years back. You can try the text mentioned in the answer. I'll remove the link.

Comment: thanks @saurabh-hooda: I hope to reach soon the 1000 emails per week so I will be able to test it

Answer (score -2):

If I understand what you're looking for, you need to disable the "People" widget. You can do that in your general settings.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general